# Thunar doesn't save settings on exit

Tags: 13.10, thunar

Every time I reboot my system,  Thunar loses its settings for view, window dimensions, column widths, etc, and reverts to its installation defaults.

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 64bit, Thunar 1.6.3.

Is there a way to make it remember its settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking and asking around, at the end I found the error:  I didn't have permissions to acces the folder ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml.

So, to be sure that the files and folders have the correct permissions, I executed this commands:

```
chmod 755 $HOME/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml
```

At the restart all work properly.

EDIT: Recursively chmod'ing /home/username to 755 as a whole is potentially dangerous, especially on multi-user machines! There are various files and folders within your $HOME that are and should be readable only to your own user. Hence the edit to chmod only the relevant directory.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue, though, only my set-up column width in Detailed View didn't get used permanently.

For me, changing the permissions (was 700) for the folder `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml` wasn't the solution. Thunar's settings got saved correctly with every switching of View mode or changing of column width. Still, every new Thunar window opened with a default column layout. Even setting permissions of `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/thunar.xml` to read-only after verifying the correctly saved settings in the XML's entry `last-details-view-column-widths` did not fix the issue; the file permissions were even reset once Thunar was restarted.

For me, the solution was to uncheck the setting **Automatically expand columns as needed** in Thunar's menu **View" > Configure Columns...**. This setting seems to work in a faulty manner, as even when opening a folder that has only one-letter items, the "Name" column was opened with a width of about 600 pixels, pushing columns such as "Type" and "Date Modified" out of view in a window 1100 Pixels wide, so I still had to scroll horizontally to see those columns.

After unchecking above setting, Thunar opens all windows and folders with the column layout I set up.

Comment: +1 I'm glad there was a proper solution/workaround (behaviour seems buggy), since chmodding files you didn't create yourself is usually a bad idea likely to cause problems down the line.

Comment: Thank you! This also worked for me on Manjaro Linux, with Thunar 1.8.9git-f98dfb.